# NGINX + Let's encrypt: Could not automatically find a matching server block

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, nginx-config, certbot

I'm publishing a website made with Python Pyramid on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. The website is running properly on HTTP and now I'm trying to make it run on HTTPS by following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) but when trying to install I get this message:

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Unable to install the certificate
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.anything.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.anything.com/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2019-03-17. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again
   with the "certonly" option. To non-interactively renew *all* of
   your certificates, run "certbot renew"
```

This is my configuration file, which lives on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/snow_service.nginx`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name dev.anything.com
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.anything.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.anything.com/privkey.pem;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 1M;

    location /static {
        gzip            on;
        gzip_buffers    8 256k;
        uwsgi_buffers   8 256k;

        alias /webapps/englobe_snow_pyramid_rest_api/pyramid_rest_api/static;
        expires 1d;
    }
    location / {
        gzip            on;
        gzip_buffers    8 256k;
        uwsgi_buffers   8 256k;

        try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }
    location @yourapplication {
        gzip            on;
        gzip_buffers    8 256k;
        uwsgi_buffers   8 256k;

        server_tokens off;
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header real_scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8999;
    }
}
```

I also tried to rename the file with the domain name but it doesn't work as well. The path for the SSL certificates I put manually because I saw it in another answer here at Stack Overflow.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12):

Here is the solution:
I was changing the file in the `sites-available` folder and not changing the file at the `sites-enabled` folder. This is the final file content:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name dev.anything.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name elglobe_snow_service
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.anything.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.anything.com/privkey.pem;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 1M;

    location /static {
        gzip            on;
        gzip_buffers    8 256k;
        uwsgi_buffers   8 256k;

        alias /webapps/englobe_snow_pyramid_rest_api/pyramid_rest_api/static;
        expires 1d;
    }
    location / {
        gzip            on;
        gzip_buffers    8 256k;
        uwsgi_buffers   8 256k;

        try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }
    location @yourapplication {
        gzip            on;
        gzip_buffers    8 256k;
        uwsgi_buffers   8 256k;

        server_tokens off;
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header real_scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8999;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact path?

Answer (score 11):

The files in `sites-enabled` should just be links to the "real" files in `sites-available`.
You should only edit the ones in `sites-available`, and then run

```sh
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
ln -s ../sites-available/your-site.conf
```

to enable that site.

If you want to disable the site, you can just delete the link in `sites-enabled`.

Comment: In my case I had `default` file in `sites-available/`. I just created a link to that file inside `sites-enabled/` as suggested above and then ran `sudo certbot --nginx` and it finally worked.

Comment: The order of paths should be file followed by directory i believe, i-e `ln -s ../sites-available/your-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Answer (score 3):

**Certbot: Could not automatically find a matching server block**

in my case, he did not detect my `/etc/nginx/site-available/my.domain.com`

```
$certbot --nginx

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Please enter the domain name(s) you would like on your certificate (comma and/or
space separated) (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

also try this

```
$ sudo certbot install --cert-name my.domain.com

Could not automatically find a matching server block for my.domain.com. Set the `server_name` directive to use the Nginx installer.
```

And try to reload and restart the Nginx, and cerbot but still no response !

"**Solution**" create the new file in `site-available/new_my.domain.com` and generate the symbolic link again `ln -s /etc/nginx/site-available/new_my.domain.com /etc/nginx/site-enabled`

then restart the Nginx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it occurred because of the Nginx config file name. I set the wrong postfix for my file (.com instead of .conf). After fixing this mistake, it worked like a charm!